# Incompresensible about $w$ $x$+ $b$ = 0

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, svm

I don't actually understand the meaning of $w$$x$ + $b$ = 0
when it is defined in support vector machine.

In my own understanding, in order for the equation to be true, the hyperplane would always need to pass through the origin.

$w$$x$ + $b$ = 0

0 = 0

But when I look at many diagram of SVM hyperplane, it doesn't pass through the origin. Which linear algebra concept am I mis-understanding or missing ?

After watching the first part of this [lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_PwhiWxHK8o&t=1129s) (as far as I could comprehend)  :

My understanding for this formalism is that we want to find a vector w which defines a hyperplane which when performing dot product with the vector w equals c.

$w$$x$ = $c$

This c is also unknown so we want to learn it. Therefore, $b$ = $-c$

$w$$x$ + $b$ = 0

However, my intuition and understanding for the topic still seems wrong for case like both side must be in null space and pass through the origin.

Comment: How about treating the minimal case where there is just a line in the Euclidian plane? What happens there?